# How to pass data to typeorm transaction

Tags: typescript, typeorm

When I read article about [typeorm transaction][1],it says that we can realize insert transactio like follows.
Following its instruction,I developed like following. But now I have question about argument `transaction`

How to pass argument of transaction to its function ? is it object data ?

```
import { Transaction} from "src/orm/typeorm/entity"
import { EntityManager } from "typeorm"

type RegisterTransactionInfo = (transaction:Transaction,createdAt:Date,createdBy:string,datasource:any) => Promise<void>

export const registerTransactionInfo: RegisterTransactionInfo = async (Transaction,createdAt,createdBy,datasource) => {

    await datasource.manager.transaction(async (transactionalEntityManager:EntityManager) =>{
       await transactionalEntityManager.save(transaction)
    })
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using Transaction type as an argument to your registerTransactionInfo function, checkout some [docs](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/transactions) about how to use it, something like this:

```
await myDataSource.manager.transaction(async (transactionalEntityManager) => {
    await transactionalEntityManager.save(users)
    await transactionalEntityManager.save(photos)
    // ...
})
```